# Static initialization block skips

Tags: java, static

The static initialization block in the non-public class `Out` doesn't run, yet the static initialization block in the static nested class `snOut` runs. How and why is this possible?

```
public class staticNested {

    static{
        System.out.println("In staticNested");
    }

    static class sn{

        static{
            System.out.println("sn in staticNested");
        }

        void p(){
            System.out.println("In static nested class method p");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        sn n = new sn();
        n.p();

        Out.snOut no = new Out.snOut();
        no.p();
    }
}

 class Out{

     static{
         System.out.println("In Out"); //Skips this
         System.out.println("Here");  //Skips this
     }

     static class snOut{

         static {
             System.out.println("In snOut in Out");
         }

            private int x;

            void p(){
                System.out.println("In snOut in outside Class out: " + x);
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the output:

```
In staticNested
sn in staticNested
In static nested class method p
In snOut in Out
In snOut in outside Class out: 0
```

Comment: I don't think class `Out` is ever loaded. It loads when you access its static field or static method, or make an instance. </ my beginner knowledge>

Comment: Ah. I see. Making a new instance in the main method makes the block run. Thanks

Comment: The difference why `Out` doesn't load and `staticNested` does is because the main is in `staticNested`, it kind of auto-loads as you would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

An instance of an inner class **I** whose declaration occurs in a static context has **no lexically enclosing instances**.

In your code you are trying to access class **sn** which is static, so it will not have any enclosing classes as per specification. That is why static block of enclosing classes are not executing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in your code you did not use the class `Out` by it self. This is the  cause, why Java didn't initialize it and didn't call its static section.

UPD.: Explanation. Your code leads to the initialization of the class `Out.snOut`, but this is not a cause for the initialization of the class `Out`.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner classes are static. This means they are just like outer classes, and an object of their type can initialize without the need of parent object. So here parent objects are never initialized and their static initializing blocks not executed.